# Converting unique values from data frame intro a reference Matrix

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have the following raw dataset

```
ID_TRIAL<-c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8)
TYPE_FAIL<-c("A","B","C","F","A","A","A","B","K","T","F","A","A","B","B","Q","P","I")
```

| ID TRIAL | TYPE_FAIL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | F |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 5 | B |
| 5 | K |
| 6 | T |
| 6 | F |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | A |
| 7 | B |
| 8 | B |
| 8 | Q |
| 8 | P |
| 8 | I |

I need to transform this dataset to create a matrix whose columns are the TYPE OF FAILS in alphabetical order and its rows are a binary representation of all unique `TYPE OF FAILS` a `TRIAL` had for instance

All the `TYPES OF FAILS` are in alphabetical order: A   B   C   F   I   K   P   Q   T

So for TRIAL 8 the matrix row will look like this

| A | B | C | F | I | K | P | Q | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

The zeros in all other cells represent that during trial 8 for example `FAIL TYPE` A did not occurred and so on.

My desired output would look like this:

| TRIAL | A | B | C | F | I | K | P | Q | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

**Some of my thought-process behind my solution:**

First I need to group by ID TRIAL then I need to find a function or a routine that will look for a letter, let's say `"B"`, and add a number one to my matrix under the column B for the row of the `TRIAL` in case. I can do this using multiple `ifelse` lines but my real dataset is quite large and I don't know if there is a way to perform this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution using `dplyr::count` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(ID_TRIAL = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 , 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8),  
                  TYPE_FAIL = c("A", "B", "C", "F", "A", "A", "A", "B", "K", "T", "F", 
                                "A", "A", "B", "B", "Q", "P", "I"))

df1 %>% 
  count(ID_TRIAL, TYPE_FAIL) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "TYPE_FAIL", 
              values_from = "n", 
              names_sort = TRUE) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 10
  ID_TRIAL     A     B     C     F     I     K     P     Q     T
     <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
         1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
         2     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
         3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
         4     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
         5     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
         6     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
         7     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
         8     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you neifws this was the faster and more efficient way I was looking for I just took a look at your wordPress blog you are one talented guy I'd love to learn a lot from! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Matrix format. Generating a matrix from the `table` returned values

```
ID_TRIAL<-c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8)  
TYPE_FAIL<-c("A","B","C","F","A","A","A","B","K","T","F","A","A","B","B","Q","P","I")

df <- data.frame(ID_TRIAL = ID_TRIAL, TYPE_FAIL = TYPE_FAIL)

mat <- table(df) |> matrix(nrow = 8, dimnames = list(unique(df$ID_TRIAL),
sort(unique(df$TYPE_FAIL))))
```

```
  A B C F I K P Q T
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
6 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
7 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

I thought you meant a literal matrix.

If you meant data.frame you can do. Using the `table` function to generate some values we can use to pivot wider

```
data.frame(table(df)) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID_TRIAL, names_from = TYPE_FAIL, values_from = Freq)
```

```
  ID_TRIAL     A     B     C     F     I     K     P     Q     T
  <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 1            1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2 2            0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
3 3            1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4 4            1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5 5            1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
6 6            1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
7 7            1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
8 8            0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Jahi! and for teaching me!